# How do I unset a relation in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

Say I have a Mongoid model, as follows:

```
class Person
  # stuff here
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups, :class_name => 'Group', :inverse_of => nil
end
```

I've just deprecated my Group model (getting rid of that class entirely), and now I want to unset that relation from all of my Person models.

What's the most appropriate way to do this? I know that Mongoid provides a way to unset fields (https://coderwall.com/p/wcx4pq/mongoid-remove-unnecessary-properties-from-documents), so I imagine there must be a way to do the same for relations so that Person no longer has `groups` or `group_ids`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only unset `group_ids` for each person object like this:

```
Person.each { |person| person.unset(:group_ids) }
```

After that you can delete groups collection.

Comment: Hm, that doesn't seem to be working - I can still access groups and group_ids. Are you sure that Mongoid treats :group_ids as a field, and not as something else? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Documents have only fields. You can access group_ids after unset them and reload objects?

Comment: Ah, now I see - I wasn't reloading. Yes, it seems like this solution works. Thanks!